# MySQL primary key must be written in parentheses

Tags: mysql, primary-key, mysql-error-1064

I have tried the following query (it was not written by myself, but was included in a source code from the Internet)

```
CREATE TABLE `city_list_count` (
  `city_created` date NOT NULL,
  `count_created` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY `city_created` 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It gave me the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying different things I've pointed out that the reason of the error is that primary key field name should be wrapped in parentheses:

```
CREATE TABLE `city_list_count` (
  `city_created` date NOT NULL,
  `count_created` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_created`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I couldn't find the explanation for this anywhere. However, it worked for me.
Just wanted to share this with others if someone came across the same trouble.

Comment: While it is not bad to post a question + answer to some problem you've faced, I'd recommend editing the question and answer so that the question part really only holds the question, and the answer part holds the answer.

Comment: Changed the question. Now it contains only the problem description. Moved my response separately.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MySQL CREATE TABLE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html), you need parentheses before and after a column list for a constraint:

> [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] PRIMARY KEY [index_type] **(index_col_name,...)**
>   [index_option] ...